# Can't delete Xcode project app from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I had a few projects that were works in progress installed on my iPhone from Xcode. I had to restore my iPhone and now I have 3 icons on my home screen that don't open anything and I can't delete. They don't go away with the tap and hold method and they don't show up in the Xcode device organizer (Command+Shift+2). Thanks in advance!

[image: my iPhone]

Comment: let me guess, ad-hoc releases?

Comment: Yep, although I am the only person running them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I encountered exact same problem. Maybe that is also Your case and hopefully - solution will help You also.

Before testflight appeared - we used our own ad-hoc solution. We had our server space where we uploaded .ipa files, and that corresponding server space had "ad-hoc scripts", so that we could download ad-hoc releases on our devices. These "scripts" contains bundle-id of the downloadable application.

In previous iOS versions (before iOS 7) - if server bundle-id did not match applications bundle id, it threw error and icon disappeared. in iOS 7, it appears that it is stuck after such case, without possibility to remove it. (Maybe not always? )

There is a possibility to remove such stuck application icons. You need to successfully install application with the bundle id of each stuck icon.

In my case - I changed applications bundle id to a new bundle id (was a project requirement), while I forgot to change bundle id on server script. Thus - ad-hoc release did not install, but the icon got stuck. Then - to remove stuck icon, I changed applications bundle id to the previous one,  Installed successfully ad-hoc release, and deleted the icon. Then I updated bundle id in application and on server part to the new one.

But, in order to do that - You need to know the bundle id of the stuck icons (check device log upon device unlocking if You don't know it?),
And You might also try to install debug version (any app will do), just simply change to the bundle id of the stuck icon bundle id. (It might work as well as ad-hoc release, but I am not sure.)

Good luck.